# Replace text with field in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

I'd like to replace every instance of

> Figure X

with the correct field:

> Figure 1

equivalent to

> Figure { SEQ Figure * ARABIC }

Can I do this natively or do I need a macro? How can I do such a macro?

Comment: The way this question is stated, it really belongs on Super User. However, the answer would be that it would require code. And at that point, the way it's stated, if you were to ask for the code, it would be "too broad"... You can certainly use (and record in a macro) Find to get the Figure text. The question then becomes: Is it better to then grab the actual figure object and use Insert Caption? Or to insert the field code directly? You might do some testing and macro recording and then, if you get stuck putting it together, include what you've come up with and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
Sub InsertSeqNo()

   Dim Rng As Range

   Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range

   Do While Rng.Find.Execute(FindText:="Figure X", Forward:=True, Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
        Rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=7
        Rng.Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="SEQ Fig \* ARABIC", PreserveFormatting:=True
   Loop

   ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```